# How is win-listview height set? - WinJS

Tags: javascript, css, windows-8, winjs, internet-explorer-10

this is driving me up the wall. I cannot figure out how to make the listview's height automatic.

i.e. have the listview's height extend in order to occupy all the space it needs and have the outer container offer a overflow-y scroll feature.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on this unforuntately.

Help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ListView controls are 400px tall by default. That's on line 1421 of the ui-light.css file. You can override it by adding a rule on your page like:

.win-listview {
    height: 100%; /* (or you can specify absolutely with something like '600px') */
}

On [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br211837.aspx) in the dev center it says...

> **Setting the ListView control's height**
>
> The ListView does not dynamically adjust its height to fit your content. For a ListView to render, you must specify an absolute value for its height. The Windows Library for JavaScript style sheets set the ListView control's height to 400 pixels.

From a design standpoint, you probably shouldn't be doing vertical scrolling on a ListView. They're designed to be laid out horizontally (as are apps in general). Combining horizontal and vertical scrolling can make for an awkward user experience. I wrote some [articles](http://codefoster.com/search.aspx?q=panning) about this.

Comment: Great reply! Thanks a lot! I have thought about using horizontal scrolling, but for certain patterns it feels quite awkward. e.g. A list of downloads, having a vertical list feels a lot more productive and intuitive.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Sometimes it's tough to think about how it will fit in a horizontal list. I'm always really impressed with the top apps (that have huge design budgets) and how they figure out how to restructure their content to fit better horizontally. In my codeSHOW app (aka.ms/codeshowapp) I show source code files and I combine horizontal and vertical. Sometimes there's no way around it.

Comment: @JeremyFoster: If you can only use absolute units, how would you render a listView so that the height of each item is equally distributed top to bottom across perhaps 5 or 6 rows? I've got a full page of results with an unsightly gap at the bottom of the page.

Should I use a repeater instead and create a custom layout using flexbox?

On an unrelated note your quick start videos got me through my 70-480 exam! Great job thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do what you're asking with the default layout of the ListView (in Windows 8.1), but you can implement a custom layout and do pretty much whatever you want. See the ListView demo in my [codeShow project](http://codeshow.codeplex.com) and check out the Circle section. That's using a custom layout.